# Failing to create a new tag badge automatically

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, tag-badges

I just noticed that I have answered 35 questions on [lua-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua-patterns) tag and [gain over 100 scores](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua-patterns/topusers). According to [Tag Badges description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua-patterns/topusers), the system is supposed to create a new bronze tag badge for this tag, but I don't see one.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tag [lua-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua-patterns) doesn't qualify for tag badges yet. The tag needs to have at least 100 questions under it before those badges can be created. It currently only has 72.